# Using Facebook php sdk v4.0 to delete individual permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk

I've built a Facebook application on my site and I'm trying to create a form to remove individual permissions.  However when I try to remove a permission I get this error.

```
 Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#100) The parameter seen_permissions is required'
```

I know I can use a try/catch to prevent the error from appearing.  My problem is, why is the error appearing in the first place? I'm using the latest php sdk (4.0.2 I think) and making the following request:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'DELETE ', '/me/permissions/'.$permission);
$response = $request->execute();
```

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#revoking) says revoking individual permissions is possible, and I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#errors) on error code 100.  Also it says 'FacebookAuthorizationException', but my session is good because I make a graph call right before this and it works fine.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you are executing an HTTP POST instead of an HTTP DELETE in the raw API call.

Only an HTTP POST to `/me/permissions` will give that error.

A guess might be the extra space in your call for DELETE might be sending a POST instead

`$request = new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'DELETE ', '/me/permissions/'.$permission);`

Should be

`$request = new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'DELETE', '/me/permissions/'.$permission);`

Comment: It was the space after DELETE.  Thanks.